# Warning/Error:- No tuples available at this result index PHP-APACHE-ODBC-MYSQL-CENTOS

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

I have PHP sample code which will fetch the data from the MYSQL database through ODBC driver on Linux(CentOS) machine.

I have created DSN and same able to connect through following command
   isql -v   
But when i try to same DSN through PHP code i am getting "No tuples available at this result index" due to which unable to read the data from database through PHP APACHE configuration.

If anyone provides the solution,It will more helpful for me to proceed further.

Below are my sample code and other details,Please correct if anything wrong on below configuration details-

### Below is sample PHP code:

```
<?php
$conn = odbc_connect("DSN", "username", "password");

$sql = 'select * from tablename';
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>User Name</th></tr>";
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
$user = odbc_result($rs,"fieldname");
 echo "<tr><td>$user</td></tr>";
}

odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

### Below is odbc.ini file:

```
[DSN]
Description             = MySQL ODBC Database
DRIVER                  = MySQL
TraceFile               = /tmp/odbcerr.log
SERVER                  = 127.0.0.1
PORT                    = 3306
USER                    = username
PASSWORD                = password
DATABASE                = database
OPTION                  = 3
SOCKET                  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

### Below is odbcinst.ini file:

```
[MySQL]
Description             = ODBC for MySQL
Driver                  = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup                   = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage               = 1
UsageCount              = 3
```

---

Comment: I realize you're just trying to get something working here, but note that `echo "<tr><td>$user</td></tr>";` injects [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)/[csrf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf) flaws into your program, unless you have significantly restricted the possible inputs for `tablename.fieldname`. You should [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) your output before sending it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

[The comments in the documentation for `odbc_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) suggest that this can be caused by using an incorrect cursor type.  Try each of the three possible values as the fourth argument: `SQL_CUR_USE_IF_NEEDED`, `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC`, or `SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER`.

I am very curious as to why you're using ODBC to connect to MySQL.  PHP has many better ways to read from MySQL, including [the *excellent* PDO class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (which itself [can connect via ODBC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) if needed).